# MS Build Error after amending wxs installer - xml file could not be found with source path

Tags: msbuild, wix

I have hit a problem which has baffled me for a day or more now. In our solution to having a large number of project files and additional solutions. So, it is quite a complex application.

Anyhow, I need to make a change to include an xml file into two exes (or msi) where when the msi is executed this xml file included in the installation folder. So, should be simple enough to do. All our installers use wixs.

Well, I updated one wix and I linked filed the xml from the source project, which has the xml file, to include in the other project where I needed to update the installer (msi). As a check, I made a new build on our build server, and it all worked. Great!

I then updated the next installer to include the xml again, and then kicked off a new build, but this failed with the error message -

"Unable to copy file `….Data.msi` to `[another location]….Data.msi`. Could not find file “….Data.msi
The file with id `…clientconfig` and name `xrmfkree.xml|clientconfig.xml` could not be found with source path `…clientconfig.xml`

I have been careful to enough that my paths are correct. Of course the source file location in the two projects will have different source locations even though the file itself is the same.

The strange thing is that the Data.msi is the msi that I did first which when I kicked off the first build worked. This error only occurred when I did the second update. Both projects are completely independent and there is no dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to set the copy to output folder